# How to execute javascript function when the user clicks on the image

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to call or execute javascript function when user click on image. I have javascript file with many functions and one of them is ShowKeybord(). So i want to execute this function ShowKeybord() when user clicks on image.

I tried with HTML parameter onclick: `<img src = "' + content + '" alt = "Heads" onclick = "ShowKeyboard()" height="170" width="170"/>` but its not working.

Here is my code of key functions that are related to my problem.

[image]

I tried with `header.addEventListener('click', ShowKeyboard)` and work properly but the keyboard is displayed when you click anywhere in the header of the web page. I would however like to make the keyboard appear only when a user clicks on the image.

What am I doing wrong and what should change depending on my code?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to enclose your image inside a div tag. As suggested by @Lucas Duval.
This should definitely work if not please give your div an "ID" or "class" and try to handle this with JQuery.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to encapsulate your img with a div with the attribute `onclick="ShowKeyboard()"`

Wich gives something like this

```
<div onclick = "ShowKeyboard()">
<img src = "' + content + '" alt ="Heads" height="170" width="170"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in the head tag put

```
<script src="yourjavascriptfilepath"></script>
```

and should work.

or maybe try `onclick="ShowKeyboard()"` rather than `onclick = "ShowKeyboard()"`

I think that has to do something with it.

Comment: I already have link to javascript file in my index.html and there is nore diference between onclick="ShowKeabord() and onclick = "ShowKeybord()"